# How to add a request logging filter in Dropwizard?

Tags: java, logging, dropwizard

I want to make filter for log requests. I have many logs like this:

```
10.244.0.74 - - [31/Mar/2021:10:14:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "kube-probe/1.19" 1
10.244.0.74 - - [31/Mar/2021:10:14:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "kube-probe/1.19" 0
10.244.0.74 - - [31/Mar/2021:10:14:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "kube-probe/1.19" 0
```

How to hide it?
Dropwizard version is 0.9.3.

Comment: Did you found solution for this issue, i have similar issue can you please help me if you have found solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.2 you can use [logging filters](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/release-1.2.x/manual/core.html#logging-filters).

In older versions, you must do the following:

1. Create a new class in extend it from `RequestLogFactory`:

   ```
   package com.service;

   import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
   import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
   import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
   import ch.qos.logback.core.CoreConstants;
   import ch.qos.logback.core.LayoutBase;
   import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl;
   import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
   import io.dropwizard.jetty.RequestLogFactory;
   import io.dropwizard.jetty.Slf4jRequestLog;
   import io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory;
   import io.dropwizard.logging.ConsoleAppenderFactory;
   import java.util.TimeZone;
   import javax.validation.Valid;
   import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
   import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
   import org.eclipse.jetty.server.RequestLog;
   import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

   public class CustomRequestLogFactory extends RequestLogFactory {

       private static final String SPAM_URI = "healthcheck";

       @NotNull
       private final TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

       @Valid
       @NotNull
       private final ImmutableList<AppenderFactory> appenders = ImmutableList.of(
           new ConsoleAppenderFactory()
       );

       private static class RequestLogLayout extends LayoutBase<ILoggingEvent> {

           @Override
           public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
               return event.getFormattedMessage() + CoreConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR;
           }
       }

       private static class CustomRequestLog extends Slf4jRequestLog {

           public CustomRequestLog(AppenderAttachableImpl<ILoggingEvent> appenders, TimeZone timeZone) {
               super(appenders, timeZone);
           }

           @Override
           public void log(Request request, Response response) {
               if (request.getUri().getCompletePath().contains(SPAM_URI)) {
                   return;
               }

               super.log(request, response);
           }
       }

       public RequestLog build(String name) {
           final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("http.request");
           logger.setAdditive(false);
           final LoggerContext context = logger.getLoggerContext();
           final RequestLogLayout layout = new RequestLogLayout();
           layout.start();
           final AppenderAttachableImpl<ILoggingEvent> attachable =
        new AppenderAttachableImpl<>();
           for (AppenderFactory output : this.appenders) {
               attachable.addAppender(output.build(context, name, layout));
           }
           return new CustomRequestLog(attachable, timeZone);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create create new Class and extend from `ServiceApplication`:

   ```
   import com.vaultcouture.service.services.CustomRequestLogFactory;
   import io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory;
   import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

   /**
    * This class is necessary for filtering logging
    */
   public class ServiceApplicationCustom extends ServiceApplication {

       @Override
       public void run(ServiceConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
           ((DefaultServerFactory) configuration.getServerFactory())
                   .setRequestLogFactory(new CustomRequestLogFactory());

           super.run(configuration, environment);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Fix `main` method:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       new ServiceApplicationCustom().run(args);
   }
   ```

Comment: You need 8 spaces (not 4) to put code in lists.